# createStoredProcedureQuery - returning wrong value?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

We have this extremely weird issue,
We see that calling an Oracle PL/SQL code (stored proc ORACLE_CALC_PRINTER_STATUS )
from java It sometimes returns Wrong results...

When we call the same function from SqlDeveloper we get the correct results...
In the java 99% of the time we get the correct results but  there are times where we don't get the correct results...

I was thinking maybe its the way we call the PL/SQL code not closing something correctly causing some weird buffer issue / exception?

But we don't see any exceptions in the logs, we see that the stored proc returns a wrong value
Its a possible value in the Stored proc, but not for the combination of inputs sent...

Hoping you guys can share anything to help debug this elusive issue.

```
    StoredProcedureQuery oracleCalcPrntrStatus = 
            entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(ORACLE_CALC_PRINTER_STATUS)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1,String.class,ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2,String.class,ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3,String.class,ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter(4,String.class,ParameterMode.OUT)
                        .setParameter(1, printerType)
                        .setParameter(2, printerId)
                        .setParameter(3, location);
    try {
            oracleCalcPrntrStatus.execute();             
            finalStatus =  (String) oracleCalcPrntrStatus.getOutputParameterValue(4);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(message, e);               
    } finally {
        oracleCalcPrntrStatus.unwrap(ProcedureOutputs.class).release();
    }
```

Stored proc skeleton:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  ORACLE_CALC_PRINTER_STATUS(PRINTER_TYPE    IN VARCHAR2, 
                                                        PRINTER_ID      IN  VARCHAR2, 
                                                        LOCATION        IN VARCHAR2, 
                                                        FINAL_STATUS    OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
EXCEPTION_STR EXCEPTION;
           
BEGIN
 IF TRIM(UPPER(PRINTER_TYPE))='XEROX'
 THEN        
  ORACLE_CALC_PRINTER_STATUS_IN      (PRINTER_TYPE,PRINTER_ID,LOCATION,FINAL_STATUS);


ELSE
RAISE EXCEPTION_STR;

END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN EXCEPTION_STR THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        
END;
```

**UPDATE** fixed missing IF/ELSE

Please understand PL/SQL code is huge and impossible to post all of it
but we did test it on the DB with the same parameters and it seems like its running ok

Comment: It is ORACLE_CALC_PRINTER_STATUS_IN procedure whose code you should have posted, it is responsible for the FINAL_STATUS OUT parameter value which is - as you said - sometimes wrong. As you didn't post its code, it is still a black box for us.

Comment: If there is an exception in the procedure, you're just writing to the `dbms_output` buffer which will almost certainly go nowhere.  So a lack of any exceptions in the log doesn't indicate that there are actually no exceptions.  The procedure you posted also appears to be invalid-- there is an `else` and an `end if` with no corresponding `if`.

Comment: That's just a *skeleton*, @Justin, so IF isn't really an issue here (at least, I think so).

Comment: I assume it's not an issue in the real code.  But when the skeleton isn't correct, it's hard to reason about what the problem might be.